# How to properly import a module that is a used by a class?

Tags: powershell, class, import, powershell-5.0

I wrote a script to wake on lan clients depending on their groups on our sccm server

The current state of the script uses 6 classes and 3 params. My problem is, that the classes use types and function of modules which I have to import. But without importing the modules in the PowerShell session before starting the script, the script runs on a TypeNotFound error and terminates.

Placing the Import-Module between param and the classes wont solve the issue. Placing the Import-Module before the param breaks the param declaration.

To me it seems, that the PowerShell compiler first takes a look at the classes and after that runs all the not class operations.

Dot-Sourcing is due to company restrictions in the environment not possible

Am I getting something wrong? How do I solve this?

The script (massively shortened):

```
param(
    
    [switch] $Herunterfahren,
    [switch] $Starten,
    [Boolean] $Test = $True

)

Import-Module Matrix42.SDK.Empirum.Powershell -ErrorAction Stop
Import-Module admpwd.ps -ErrorAction Stop

Class JsonSettings {
}

Class Logger {
}

Class EmpirumConnector {

    [Boolean] $isConnected = $False

    hidden [String] $encryptedPassword
    hidden [String] $serverAddress
    hidden [String] $databaseUser
    hidden [int] $port
    hidden [String] $protocol
    hidden [Boolean] $secureConnection

    hidden [Matrix42.SDK.Contracts.ISession] $connection = $null

    hidden [String] $logModule = 'Empirum'

}

Class RemoteControl {
}

Class StartClients {
}

Class ShutdownClients {
}

[Logger]::GetInstance().Info('Starter', 'call with params', [PSCustomObject]@{
    Herunterfahren = $Herunterfahren
    Starten = $Starten
    Test = $Test
}, $null)

if ($Herunterfahren -and $Starten) {
    [Logger]::GetInstance().Error('Starter', "illegal call with params. Herunterfahren and Starten not allowed")
} elseif (-not $Herunterfahren -and -not $Starten) {
    [Logger]::GetInstance().Error('Starter', "illegal call with params. Herunterfahren or Starten must be present")
} elseif ($Starten) {
    [StartClients]::new().run()
} elseif ($Herunterfahren) {
    [ShutdownClients]::new().run()
}

[Logger]::GetInstance().SaveToXml()
```

Exact problem is:
Class EmpirumConnector is using type Matrix42.SDK.Contracts.ISession for the connection property which is contained in the Matrix42.SDK.Empirum.Powershell module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a module loaded at parse-time, you have to declare it with a [`using module` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.1#module-syntax):

```
using module Matrix42.SDK.Empirum.Powershell
using module admpwd.ps

param(
    [switch] $Herunterfahren,
    [switch] $Starten,
    [Boolean] $Test = $True
)

Class EmpirumConnector {

    [Boolean] $isConnected = $False

    hidden [String] $encryptedPassword
    hidden [String] $serverAddress
    hidden [String] $databaseUser
    hidden [int] $port
    hidden [String] $protocol
    hidden [Boolean] $secureConnection

    hidden [Matrix42.SDK.Contracts.ISession] $connection = $null # this can now be resolved by the type definer

    hidden [String] $logModule = 'Empirum'

}

# ...
```